# Saving two streams of one of video and other audio using Xuggler and Red5

Tags: java, actionscript-3, apache-flex, xuggle, xuggler

I am using a red5 server. I am doing a two way video conference using flex application. My current red5 server is storing both streams as different flv files.

now i have done some editing and have saved these edited files as one with video stream

> (OutputVideo.flv)

and one with Audio Stream

> (OutputAudio.mp3)

.

Now i want to join these videos into one flv

> (Output.flv)

How can i do that using xuggler.

Please if anyone can help me or at least provide me some hints. Note that i am using eclispe java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just starting to look into xuggler, so this answer is untested.  From [this tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/xuggler-tutorial-transcoding-media.html), it looks like you create a chain of commands:

```
[...]
// create a tool chain:
// reader -> addStaticImage -> reduceVolume -> writer
mediaReader.addListener(imageMediaTool);
imageMediaTool.addListener(audioVolumeMediaTool);
audioVolumeMediaTool.addListener(mediaWriter);
[...]
```

These don't have to be the same streams, as I understand it; they just have to be chained.  Sorry I am not more help, but hopefully someone can correct any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890666/how-to-join-one-audio-and-video-file-xuggler/11843385#11843385) 
Can merge audio and video file and the resulting file will be nicely synchronized.