# How to merge an Audio and Video files in Android

Tags: android, video, video-capture, video-processing

I have a small video clip and an audio file. The problem is how to write code to merge them into a single file. i have never written code for multimedia applications for android and don't know if the merging is possible with android media framework. Is there any third party library to do that?

Can we right a merging code in Java and call it in Android?

Please guide me through this. Thanks

Comment: Did you come across this?....http://superuser.com/questions/285151/ffmpeg-too-slow-audio-and-video-merging

Comment: yes I have seen, ffmpeg, basically I want a single .apk android package file which which will install in android and do the merging process for two files 1. Custom Audio file 2. Video file captured from Android Camera. how can I use ffmpeg.exe in Android?

Comment: Is there any way to use xuggler http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890666/how-to-join-one-audio-and-video-file-xuggler in Android if yes then how?

Comment: did u get the answer for this?

Comment: Did any of the 3 of you find an answer ?

Answer (score -1):

You can try INDE Media for Mobile, tutorials are here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-inde-media-pack-for-android-tutorials

It has a sample demonstating how to substitute audio track in mp4 video file by another audio track from another mp4 file. It's here:  https://github.com/INDExOS/media-for-mobile/blob/master/Android/samples/effects/src/com/intel/inde/mp/effects/SubstituteAudioEffect.java

In sample app it's under Audio Effect:

[image]