# How to merge an audio file with an image or video file in android?

Tags: android, audio, video, merge, video-capture

I want to apply a functionality in that i have to merge a recorded audio with an image to whole audio or with an video. I tried a lot but not getting how to play an audio with an image/video of its background.
Please help me out from this trouble.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to merge an audio to an image to create a video or you want an app to play audio when viewing an image ?be specific

Comment: @Tapesh, Have you found any solution?Please see my answer i posted below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I post an answer one of similar question.

[FFMPEG:Multiple Image frames + 1 Audio =1 Video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20463719/ffmpegmultiple-image-frames-1-audio-1-video/21304505#21304505)

I hope this will help.Thanks!

Comment: Can you please tell me how to put a commentary audio over the video file?? I mean is it possible that 2 audio play or record together on one video ?

Comment: @ArslanAhmad, You can you ffmpeg android library for this issue.

Comment: Yeah I m using the same library but I need to audio mixing in video ?

Answer (score 0):

->Option one:

I really don't understand what you exactly asking about. If you want to show image with background audio then, you can start both simultaneously. So that the UI display the image and in background the audio will get started. But make sure on how to get rid of that.

-> Option two:

I googled reg what you asked, and i found some basic tutorials which can able to merge audio and image files together. Go-through the following link: [Link from stackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890666/how-to-join-one-audio-and-video-file-xuggler), [Sample code](https://code.google.com/p/xuggle/source/browse/trunk/java/xuggle-xuggler/src/com/xuggle/mediatool/demos/ConcatenateAudioAndVideo.java). Hope this will help you out. If my answer is wrong, kindly rectify me. Thanks.

Comment: Okay. Thanks Hari i got solution of it. thanks to show your keen intrest. :)